# What size are the replacement o rings in the prestacycle set?

Tags: pump

https://www.crosslakesales.com/products/prestacycle-prestaflator-tool-rebuild-kit-o-ring-new

I asked the company that manufactures them, they said they didn't know.

Does anyone know the sizes? I ask because the set is not available in the UK. Flying it over the Atlantic seems ridonkulous when I could just buy some o rings here.

Comment: Do you not have the old o-rings?

Comment: If you have the old rings, measure them.  Or, better, take them to a shop and find a match.

Comment: I bought a cheap multipack of "various sizes" of O rings for about $4.  It will probably be a standard size.  Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have the old one i need. It disintegrated and I threw it away before i thought to measure it

Comment: I'd go with criggie's approach then. Maybe take the inflator tool to the hardware shop and compare with a few there.

Comment: I bought replacement O-rings at my local bike shop. They had them in stock.

Comment: https://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=98387

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got mine from AliExpress 10X5X2.5mm O seal ring for US$2.

Tested it and it fix perfect.

Answer (score 6):

**Based on the photo in the question** the big O ring is 12 mm outside to outside.   The O ring rubber is 2 mm thick.

Googling tells me:

> O-rings made from high quality buna-nitrile (BN70) rubber with a durometer rating of 70.

[image: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0360/5145/products/364670-5_30b26b5e-ef96-4c0a-bfdd-11a75617295e_1024x1024.jpg?v=1505314851]

This is proportional to the inventory sticker being 12.0mm high as per all the ones I found in my house.

There appear to be two other sizes in the bag as well, one smaller and one thicker like a tap washer.

[image: Own work]

Given this bag of parts is **$3.95 USD** from several LBS and from Amazon its hardly worth messing about.  If the freight is too much, ask for an envelope not a parcel or order more things to make it worthwhile.

Comment: Stressing that this is an estimate based on the photo, not a qualified measurement from a sample.

Comment: Yeah it's more I don't want to rack up the air miles.  Good skills with the image! :)